# Flutter Http status error [415] (using Retrofit)

Tags: flutter, http, retrofit, dio

I'm trying to send http request using [Retrofit](https://pub.dev/packages/retrofit) code generation.

**I'm getting status 415, even though I added `Accept` json and `Content-Type` json to the header.**

> DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [415]

My retrofit code:

```
@POST('/users')
  Future<dynamic> users(
    @Body() Map<String, String> request, {
    @Header('accept') String accept = 'application/json',
    @Header('content-type') String contentType = 'application/json',
  });
```

The generated code:

```
@override
  Future<dynamic> users(request,
      {accept = 'application/json', contentType = 'application/json'}) async {
    const _extra = <String, dynamic>{};
    final queryParameters = <String, dynamic>{};
    final _headers = <String, dynamic>{
      r'accept': accept,
      r'content-type': contentType
    };
    _headers.removeWhere((k, v) => v == null);
    final _data = request;
    final _result = await _dio.fetch(_setStreamType<dynamic>(Options(
            method: 'POST',
            headers: _headers,
            extra: _extra,
            contentType: contentType)
        .compose(_dio.options, '/users',
            queryParameters: queryParameters, data: _data)
        .copyWith(baseUrl: baseUrl ?? _dio.options.baseUrl)));
    final value = _result.data;
    return value;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved!

Since the request type is `Map<String, String>`, I had to change the `content-type` to **`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`**

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
"Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf8"
```

Comment: Still getting 415 :\

Comment: Change to "accept": "/" in your code

Comment: What are you talking about? Add explanation.